# How do GPU/PPU timings work on the Gameboy?

Tags: gpu, emulation, timing, gameboy

I’m writing a gameboy emulator and I’ve come to implementing the graphics. However I can’t quite figure out how it works with the cpu as far as timing/clock cycles go. Does the CPU execute a certain amount of cycles (if so how many) and then hand it of to the GPU? Or is the gameboy always in a hblank/vblank state and the GPU uses the CPU in between them? I can’t find any information that helps me with this, only how to use the control registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link gives more of a general answer instead of implementation specifics, so I want to give my 2 cents.

CPU usually is the main part of your emulator and what actually counts cycles. Each time your CPU does something for any amount of cycles you pass that amount of cycles to other components of your emulator so that they can synchronize themselves.

For example, some CPU instructions read and write memory as part of a single instruction. That means is would take Gameboy CPU 4 (read) + 4 (write) cycles to complete the instruction. So in emulator you do the read, pass 4 cycles to GPU, do the write, pass 4 cycles to GPU. You do the same for other components that run parallel to the CPU like timers and sound.

It's actually important to do it that way instead of emulating whole instruction and then synchronizing everything else. Don't know about real ROMs but there're test ROMs that verify this exact behavior. 8 cycles is a long time and in the middle of multiple memory accesses some other Gameboy component might make a change.

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered at https://forums.nesdev.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=17754&p=225009#p225009

It turns out I had it completely wrong and they are completely different.

Here is the post:

> The Game Boy CPU and PPU run in parallel. The 4.2 MHz master clock is
>   also the dot clock. It's divided by 2 to form the PPU's 2.1 MHz memory
>   access clock, and divided by 4 to form a multi-phase 1.05 MHz clock
>   used by the CPU.
>
> Each scanline is 456 dots (114 CPU cycles) long and consists of mode 2
>   (OAM search), mode 3 (active picture), and mode 0 (horizontal
>   blanking). Mode 2 is 80 dots long (2 for each OAM entry), mode 3 is
>   about 168 plus about 10 more for each sprite on a given line, and mode
>   0 is the rest. After 144 scanlines are drawn are 10 lines of mode 1
>   (vertical blanking), for a total of 154 lines or 70224 dots per
>   screen. The CPU can't see VRAM (writes are ignored and reads are $FF)
>   during mode 3, but it can during other modes. The CPU can't see OAM
>   during modes 2 and 3, but it can during blanking modes (0 and 1).